# iSCSI + br0 bridge + 14.04.1 Server = does not work

Tags: networking, server, dhcp, kvm-virtualization, network-bridge

On one of my servers I have:
USB 4GB:

```
1) EFI partition
2) /boot partition
```

iSCSI 50GB (on another fileserver):

```
3) / partition
```

In /etc/network/interfaces it works flawlessly if I have:

```
auto p3p1
iface p3p1 inet dhcp
```

As soon as I change it to this, it won't boot no matter what (it must be this file because it won't boot when I change it):

```
auto p3p1
iface p3p1 inet dhcp

auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
bridge_ports    p3p1
bridge_stp      off
bridge_maxwait  0
bridge_fd       0
```

This server is gonna be a KVM host and I might make more of them in the future, so local HDD is not an option (only iSCSI is).

Answer (score 0):

I think the p3p1 interface stanza should read

```
auto p3p1
iface p3p1 inet manual
```

I've just set up a server like this and that is the only difference between your config and mine.

My working config is

```
# The primary network interface
auto p1p1
iface p1p1 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
        address 192.168.0.67
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.0.1
        bridge_ports p1p1
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_maxwait  0
        bridge_fd       0
```

Hope that helps.